# TorchText Vocab TypeError: Vocab.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_freq'

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tokenize, imdb, torchtext

I am working on a CNN Sentiment analysis machine learning model which uses the IMDb dataset provided by the Torchtext library.
On one of my lines of code

`vocab = Vocab(counter, min_freq = 1, specials=('\<unk\>', '\<BOS\>', '\<EOS\>', '\<PAD\>'))`

I am getting a TypeError for the min_freq argument even though I am certain that it is one of the accepted arguments for the function. I am also getting UserWarning Lambda function is not supported for pickle, please use regular python function or functools partial instead. Full code

```
from torchtext.datasets import IMDB
from collections import Counter
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import Vocab
tokenizer = get_tokenizer('basic_english')  
train_iter = IMDB(split='train')
test_iter = IMDB(split='test')
counter = Counter()
for (label, line) in train_iter:
    counter.update(tokenizer(line))
vocab = Vocab(counter, min_freq = 1, specials=('\<unk\>', '\<BOS\>', '\<EOS\>', '\<PAD\>'))
```

Source Links
[towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/cnn-sentiment-analysis-9b1771e7cdd6)
[github Legacy to new](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb)

I have tried removing the min_freq argument and use the functions default as follows

`vocab = Vocab(counter, specials=('\<unk\>', '\<BOS\>', '\<EOS\>', '\<PAD\>'))`

however I end up getting the same type error but for the specials argument rather than min_freq.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/1445 mentioned, you should change "Vocab" to "vocab". I think they miss-type the legacy-to-new notebook.

correct code:

```
from torchtext.datasets import IMDB
from collections import Counter
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import vocab
tokenizer = get_tokenizer('basic_english')  
train_iter = IMDB(split='train')
test_iter = IMDB(split='test')
counter = Counter()
for (label, line) in train_iter:
    counter.update(tokenizer(line))
vocab = vocab(counter, min_freq = 1, specials=('\<unk\>', '\<BOS\>', '\<EOS\>', '\<PAD\>'))
```

my environment:

- python 3.9.12
- torchtext 0.12.0
- pytorch 1.11.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try torchtext.legacy.vocab instead of torchtext.vocab which might solve the issue. This worked for me:

```
from torchtext.datasets import IMDB
from collections import Counter
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.legacy.vocab import vocab
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it doesn't work for me. :(
Vocab is correct name of object and vocab is not.

Simply solution I found is: that "specials" tuple was removed from experimental Vocab and in no more in use! That's all.

https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/890

my environment:

```
python 3.8.16
torchtext 0.15.1
pytorch 2.0.0
```